# Graphql web socket connection failed over production

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, graphql

I Have tried every possible Nginx config but it's showing connection failed every time.

config file:

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    }

    location /graphql {
    proxy_pass         https://bakbakgraphql.com/graphql;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: from what url is the service actually running? Is the root location working?

Comment: Yes, the root location working and I am able to make normal HTTPS calls.

Comment: Your proxy_http_version is 1.1, Did you try using ws insteads of wss?

Comment: @Salemloress Yes, I have tried this and it won't work as my page is loaded over HTTPS.